Copying text to clipboard in Neovim
Details of my problem
I want to copy text from Neovim to my MacOS/Windows system clipboard. Using commands or keyboard shortcut keys.
What I tried
I tried methods provided by chatbots, but they didn't work.
Please help, thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can add this to your vimrc file:
set clipboard+=unnamedplus

It will make Neovim communicate with the system clipboard.
ref: Allow Neovim To Copy/Paste With System Clipboard

Above is the right answer in my opinion.
If it doesn't solve it for you, then you might find help by checking following
:checkhealth provider.clipboard

and
:help clipboard

Also if you prefer to use lua in your config, then instead of the above answer you can use
vim.opt.clipboard = "unnamedplus"


From what I've heard, using the command set clipboard+=unnamedplus allows you to use the clipboard directly, just like Neovim's buffer.
Personally, I don’t like this option because when you copy something and then delete a letter with x, you lose the copied text from your clipboard.
To copy text, just use the normal y, but prepend the command with "+, for example, to copy an entire line: "+yy.
To paste is just the same, prepend "+.
I hope I have answered your question.
